# Error installing cucumber in Windows 8

Tags: ruby, installation, cucumber

I am following a book to install cucumber on my windows 8 machine but I have encountered an error.

The steps I have taken so far are:

1. Installed Ruby by using Ruby Installer
2. Installed Ruby Installer development kit
3. Installed ANSICON
4. Installed Bundler

I am having problems installing Cucumber itself. Here is the console output:

```
C:\>gem install cucumber
Fetching: builder-3.2.2.gem (100%)
Successfully installed builder-3.2.2
Fetching: diff-lcs-1.2.4.gem (100%)
Successfully installed diff-lcs-1.2.4
Fetching: multi_json-1.7.6.gem (100%)
Successfully installed multi_json-1.7.6
Fetching: gherkin-2.12.0.gem (100%)
ERROR:  Error installing cucumber:
        The 'gherkin' native gem requires installed build tools.

Please update your PATH to include build tools or download the DevKit
from 'http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads' and follow the instructions
at 'http://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit'
```

I am new to Cucumber and have no ruby experience. Help would be appreciated.

Comment: What's the name of the book you are following to install?

Answer (score 3):

When you uncompress the devkit, you should install and configure the devkit. 
To configure devkit for all your ruby versions :

```
ruby dk.rb init
```

To install and finish :

```
ruby dk.rb install
```

Answer (score 0):

In your error is the supposed answer.  It looks like you're on Windows, you need some form of compiler to build the native-code portion of them gherkin gem.

[This link discusses what's going on.](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Development-Kit)

and [Here is a link to the DevKit installers](http://rubyinstaller.org/downloads/), it looks like it's a [MinGW](http://www.mingw.org)-based system (basically GCC on Windows).

**edit**: Whoops, looks like you installed the DevKit.  Sounds like you skipped or incorrectly performed a step and it can't find it, not really a Ruby issue.